# pandas.Index.isin produces a different dataframe than simple slicing

Tags: python, pandas

I'm really new to pandas and python in general, so I apologize if this is too basic.

I have a list of indices that I must use to take a subset of the rows of a dataframe. First, I simply sliced the dataframe using the indices to produce (`df_1`). Then I tried to use `index.isin` just to see if it also works (`df_2`). Well, it works but it produces a shorter dataframe (and seemingly ignores some of the rows that are supposed to be selected).

```
df_1 = df.iloc[df_idx]

df_2 = df[df.index.isin(df_idx)]
```

So my question is, why are they different? How exactly does index.isin work and when is it appropriate to use it?

Comment: Can you show the contents of ``df_1`` & ``df_2`` ?

Comment: The dataframes are pretty large, so it's not really feasible. `df_1.shape=(133416, 5)`, `df_2.shape=(121232, 5)`. Also `len(df_idx)=133416`. So `df_2` is definitely missing many rows.

Answer (score 1):

Synthesising duplicates in index and then it re-produces the behaviour you note.  If your index has duplicates it's absolutely expected the two will give different results.  If you want to use these interchangeably you need to ensure that your index values uniquely identify a row

```
n = 6
df = pd.DataFrame({"idx":[i//2 for i in range(n)],"col1":[f"text {i}" for i in range(n)]}).set_index("idx")

df_idx = df.index

print(f"""
{df}
{df.iloc[df_idx]}
{df[df.index.isin(df_idx)]}
""")
```

**output**

```
       col1
idx        
0    text 0
0    text 1
1    text 2
1    text 3
2    text 4
2    text 5
       col1
idx        
0    text 0
0    text 0
0    text 1
0    text 1
1    text 2
1    text 2
       col1
idx        
0    text 0
0    text 1
1    text 2
1    text 3
2    text 4
2    text 5
```